# How to store an identity for guest user in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and for a starter learning project, I was developing an E-commerce website using Laravel. I want to develop the cart functionalities but got stuck at a point.If a logged in user clicks "Add to Cart" button for an item, it gets stored in the database and that item in cart gets related to the particular user ID and that's how I know what user have what items in cart. But how can I handle users who don't have an account? Not all users always create accounts when they use an Ecommerce platform. What relation can I use for guest users ?

P.s. I know there are several cart functionalities available on Github for handling cart but I wanted to implement that myself

Please help me with this

Comment: There is plenty of ways to store product ID's, its not the best way in my opinion to ever store pending cart product ids to database, unless you want to implement winback marketing, send email notifications about pending cart etc. I'd look solution from storing product ids to session, cookies or even local storage if you want to process orders using ajax requests. No reason to reinvent the wheel, unless you want to practise. But I would go with some Laravel library that does this for you.

Comment: session table redis

Comment: yes I wanted to learn. Also I am storing cart data into database so that a user adds stuff to cart and can easily checkout whever they want.If i store that in session, it will just go away when user logs out of closes the browser

Comment: Ideal solution is something that works for guests and members, I would go with cookies or local storage in this case.